# What is the literature on optimizing for maximum nodes in a graph without cycles?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have an arbitrary directed, non-complete graph.  I would like to find a maximal subset of nodes within that graph such that the induced subgraph has no cycles.  I'm sure there must be a name for this problem in the literature - do you know what it is?

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know how I can mark the question as answered, given that you answered in a comment?

Comment: I just transferred my comment to answer.  So I will delete that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "maximum acyclic subgraph" problem (just search Google).

I once used such a thing for an info-theory bound on an "index coding" problem (but for a directed graph in that case), Lemma 1 here:

http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/dynamic-index-coding-it.pdf